# I get always that java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, mocking

i added a mocked user this my class

```
@TestConfiguration
public class UserDetailsMock {

    final String apiAccessGroup = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        User ericssonUser = new User("ericsson-worker", "secret", Arrays.asList());
        User msApiUser = new User("msApiUser", "StrongPass", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(apiAccessGroup)));

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(Arrays.asList(
                ericssonUser, msApiUser
        ));
    }
}
```

and this my test Class any help please!!!!

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = UserDetailsMock.class
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MuninServiceAuthorizationTest {

    @Autowired
     MockMvc mockMvc;

     List<MockHttpServletRequestBuilder> endpoints;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

        endpoints = Arrays.asList(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/migrate/foss").with(csrf()),
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/swagger/ui/**"));

    }
    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("msApiUser")
    void userWithGroupWhichIsAllowedToUseApiShouldGet200() throws Exception {
        for (MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder : endpoints) {
            mockMvc.perform(mockHttpServletRequestBuilder)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? What have you tried to fix the issues?

Comment: when i tried to test userWithGroupWhichIsAllowedToUseApiShouldGet200() with a mockUser i am getting always ==> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Comment: You should add that to the body of the question, not just the title or the comments. It makes it easier to notice what the question really is. And it better fits the standard format of questions on this site. In general, anything that is pertinent information to help figure out what's going on needs to be in the body of the question. And code examples should be minimal examples of what's wrong, as well as actual working code. When I edited your question, I had to add a closing bracket. Not a big deal, but some people might have a problem with it (for future reference).

Comment: ok thank you for the editing it looks better now ..